# How to load menu only once time in Master Page?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I created Master page which has got mainNavigator panel on top of page that is a web user control(BuildMenu.ascx). I am filling UC Menu in master page's loading :

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="IntermMaster.master.cs" Inherits="MyProject.IntermMaster" EnableViewState="true"  %>

<%@ Register src="Utils/BuildMenu.ascx" tagname="BuildMenu" tagprefix="uc1" %>

>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <uc1:BuildMenu ID="BuildMenu2" runat="server"  />
   </div>
    <div>

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

This is loading in postback event:

BuildMenu.ascx.cs

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                 // Fill Menu from DataBase (Compare SiteMap...)
            }
```

Every post back BuildManu.ascx is loading every time tihs is really bored me. How can i solve it. I want to  do only one time load BuildMenu.ascx (in master page)

[image]

Comment: The control is always loaded again, if only to review whether anything has changed. The rendered control is cached so in case nothing has changed there will be no more computing time spent for the control to be displayed, it will use the cached version. You shouldn't worry about this, the cache will save your performance and in case something changes in your control you don't have to flush the cache to see the change. Personally I think this is the desired behaviour IMHO. Open for discussion obviously...

Comment: @Bazzz; i agree with you please think a minute. i think that it is really really Bullshit. why can i fill only content place holder....

Answer (score 3):

Unless you want to use frames (and you probably do not), the control has to be reloaded each time so it can be rendered.  The best you can do is to use server-side output caching so that it takes less processing time to load the control.

To do output caching, put this in your page:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="[Number of Seconds]" VaryByParam="None" %>
```

Comment: thanks but i add master page not working i erased from master i add any web page not working :(

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "not working?"  Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1):

The load method **WILL** be called every time a postback occures (except for AJAX pages, but let's not go there). Take a look at the [ASP.NET page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

What you can do is just return from the controls Load event if the value of IsPostBack is true.

However, if the control in question is static (or almost static) in content you could try using [output cashing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx) on the server, that way the control will be loaded once in a while, and the rest of the times, the server will just use it's cashed copy.

Comment: +1 for the link to the ASP.NET page lifecycle document.  @Phsika, that's the single-most useful read on understanding how ASP.NET Web Forms work.

Answer (score 0):

i have a better idea why dont you sue a session it will help you

make like this ::

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        if session(ispostback") <> "menuloaded"
        {
             // Fill Menu from DataBase (Compare SiteMap...)
             Session("ispostback")="menuloaded" 
        }
```

this will work for sure